# Is there any strongly polynomial time algorithm to check nonnegativity of a univariate polynomial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algorithms, computational-complexity

There are algorithms which can do this e.g. GCD based techniques, but their running time depends on the description length of the coefficients. I am trying to find out if there exists an algorithm do determine this whose running time does not depend of the description length of the coefficients.

Comment: Well, you'll have to read all coefficients and so have to spend at least $\Omega(n)$ time, where $n$ is the description length of the coefficients.

Comment: The question is whether the number of flops necessary is independent of the size of the coefficients. For example, for unsolvable univariate polynomials of degree bigger than 4, the running time of root finding using bisection or some similar method depends on the size of the coefficients. For univariate polynomials of degree up to 4, the roots can be written as algebraic formulae of the coefficients, so the running time is fixed. Reading and writing numbers are not supposed to be counted in building an algorithm, only during practical impelemntation.